# "Difficulty of" vs. "difficulty in"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

In the sentence:

> I understand the difficulty **of** remaining objective.

Should it be as is, or should it be like this:

> I understand the difficulty **in** remaining objective.

Comment: Either would work. You could also use *with*. That's English for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you think that either might be ‘a horrible sentence’?

The two would be used on different occasions. ‘The difficulty of remaining objective’ states a general principle. ‘The difficulty in remaining objective’ would be more appropriate in a particular case. It might even apply to a case in which someone had **already** remained objective, or was on the point of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Either form is fine.

I prefer, "I understand the difficultly *in* remaining objective": there is perhaps slightly more emphasis on the "remaining", on involvement in an action, a struggle.

One would not say, "I had no difficulty *of* remaining objective", or, "I had the difficulty *in* remaining objective" - does that help to clarify the distinction?

No? Okay, instead how about, "I understand that it can be difficult to remain objective".

*"Yes sir, so it is claimed."*